# How to fix errno=24 in QuestDB?

Tags: docker, questdb

I run QuestDB and sometimes I have my WAL tables suspended with the error message

```
2023-12-04T13:32:29.490424Z C i.q.c.w.ApplyWal2TableJob job failed, table suspended [table=..., error=could not open read-only [file=/.../column.d], errno=24]
```

I read that errno 24 means open file limit and followed instructions to increase the file limit on my Ubuntu 22.04 which is my Docker Host OS. Unfortunately, I still see the error 24 in the logs.

How to increase the file limit for the QuestDB running in the docker and how to check what limit is applied to the process?